# Why does this function involving trigonometric functions produce $f(10^{-2n})\approx \{10^n, 0<n<8 \text{ and } \sqrt{2}\cdot 10^n,n\geq 8\}$?

Tags: functions, asymptotics, approximation, mathematica

Why does the function $$f(\gamma)=\sqrt{2}\left[\ln\left( 1+ \frac{2}{\cot (\gamma/2)-1} \right) + \sec \gamma \tan \gamma\right]^{-1/2}$$ produce $$f(10^{-2n})\approx \cases{10^n \hspace{1.35cm} , \; 0<n<8 \\ \sqrt{2}\cdot10^n \quad , \; n\geq 8} \quad ?$$

I stumbled upon this by accident, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what would produce such a behavior!

Here are some results from Mathematica:

```
In = Table[N[f[10^(-2 n)]], {n, 1, 20}]
Out = {9.99975, 100., 1000., 10000., 100000., 999978., 1.0002*10^7, 
1.41421*10^8, 1.41421*10^9, 1.41421*10^10, 1.41421*10^11, 
1.41421*10^12, 1.41421*10^13, 1.41421*10^14, 1.41421*10^15, 
1.41421*10^16, 1.41421*10^17, 1.41421*10^18, 1.41421*10^19, 
1.41421*10^20}
```

This clearly shows the "transition" of the coefficients $1 \rightarrow \sqrt{2}$. The ratio between consecutive terms seems to stabilize (the exception being that pesky sixth to last $4.59372$), so it behaves somewhat exponentially for $\gamma \rightarrow 0$:

```
In = Table[N[f[10^(-(n + 1))]/f[10^(-n)]], {n, 1, 20}]
Out = {3.17014, 3.16236, 3.16228, 3.16228, 3.16228, 3.16228, 3.16228, \
3.16228, 3.16228, 3.16228, 3.16221, 3.16298, 3.16228, 3.07797, \
4.59372, 3.16228, 3.16228, 3.16228, 3.16228, 3.16228}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the syntax for f[x_], as requested:

```
f[t_] = Sqrt[2/(Log[1 + 2/(-1 + Cot[t/2])] + Sin[t]/Cos[t]^2)]
```

Comment: Could you provide the syntax used for $f[x] := $ ? Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Certainly, edited :)

Comment: Thanks ! I shall go to university tomorrow morning to play with it. If I find anything funny, I shall post. In any manner, @gammatester gave a very good explanation.

Comment: @Indeed he did! If you want, see my comment for an update on what is puzzling to me as of now. And thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told, I went to university and a former colleague of mine compared

```
 f[t_] = Sqrt[2/(Log[1 + 2/(-1 + Cot[t/2])] + Sin[t]/Cos[t]^2)]
 data1 = Table[N[f[10^(-2 n)]], {n, 1, 50}]
 data2 = Table[N[f[10^(-2 n)],6], {n, 1, 50}]
```

The first data contains your surprizing results while the second one does not and produced the expected result which correspond to $$f(t)=\frac 1{\sqrt t}-\frac 14 t^{3/2}+ O(t^{7/2})$$ $$f(10^{-2n})\approx10^n$$

Similarly, using

```
 Table[N[f[10^(-(n + 1))]/f[10^(-n)],6], {n, 1, 20}]
```

generates the correct numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Because $\ln\left( 1+ \frac{2}{\cot (\gamma/2)-1} \right)$ is computed as $\ln(1)=0$ in floating point for larger $n$. Use the function $\mathrm{ln1p}$ or $\mathrm{log1p}$  if available. If not write your own function $\ln(1+x)$, see e.g. Theorem 4 in D. Goldberg, What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic, 1991 (extended and edited reprint via http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768)

Comment: Okay, so $f(\gamma)\approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\sin \gamma}}\approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\gamma}}$ for small $\gamma$ (if I'm not mistaken and have not reduced the expression too much)? This explains the $10^{-2n} \rightarrow \sqrt{2}\cdot 10^n$-behaviour, but what is so special about the step $n=7 \rightarrow n=8$ then? What cancels out the $\sqrt{2}$, and why is the transition so sudden?

Comment: @Lovsovs. At this level, nothing will be gradual, I bet.

Comment: I do not use Mathematica, but I can reproduce your values. I guess you use IEEE double arithmetic with a machine $\epsilon =  2.220446\times 10^{-16}.$ (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).
Then you have $1+x=1$ for $x=10^{-16}$ but $1.00000000000001$ for $x=10^{-14}.$ Remember $ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3$ for small $x$.

Comment: a) Is "machine $\epsilon$" explained in the article you linked to? b) How does that $0.0\dots 01$ result in the $\sqrt{2}$ being cancelled for lower values of $n$? Could you show this? I'm having a hard time seeing it. c) Does this mean that there is nothing mathematical about this pattern, i.e. that it is an artifact of the floating point arithmetic (and the associated rounding errors)? Thanks.

Comment: For small $x$ you have
$$\ln(1+2/(\cot(x/2)-1))+\mathrm{sec}(x) \tan(x)= 2x+ x^3+O(x^5)$$
$$\mathrm{sec}(x) \tan(x)= x+5/6 x^3+ O(x^5)$$
this gives the factor $2$ if the argument to $\ln$ is rounded to $1$

Comment: Using your definition, for small $t$, $$f(t)=\frac 1{\sqrt t}-\frac 14 t^{3/2}+ O(t^{7/2})$$

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: Yes, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2t}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$